# Same photo at different time?

Tags: post-processing, autofocus, technique, timelapse, shooting-technique

I want to take photos how some places look now. I have photos how they looked few years ago but I can't shot the photo at the same angle. Any idea how this can be done?

Examples:

http://dcist.com/attachments/pablo_maurer/poc7.gif
http://dcist.com/attachments/pablo_maurer/outdoorpool.gif

Comment: perspective can be corrected in photoshop

Comment: Please read [Important information for asking "What's this effect?"
questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/) and
edit this post accordingly. Make sure to use a descriptive title, 
too. Thank you!

Comment: You've posted examples what you're trying to achieve, but you haven't posted your attempts. Please upload the old photo, and the photo of your attempt to recreate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine camera location from an existing photograph?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50816/how-to-determine-camera-location-from-an-existing-photograph)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say you can't shoot at the same angle, do you mean because it's difficult to figure out exactly where the photo was taken originally, or do you mean it's impossible because of some physical change, i.e. new construction, demolished building etc?

If it's the former, just have a copy of the original photograph with you, and try different locations and angles, paying attention to specific features in the scene. Try to match areas at the corners if possible. If the corners are all correct, then the rest of the photo will be also. A complicating factor would be if you don't know what type of lens was used originally. If you can't be sure the focal length matches, it will be extremely difficult to get the picture to look correct.

If you don't physically have access to shoot from the same location, then you'll need to get as close as you can, and then correct the perspective in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

its going to be trial and error mostly, you could... if you have a camera that will sync to smart phone. Sync your camera and viewing the live scene on the the phone swap to the old photo to get the angles correct while moving the camera position (would be easier if you had a helper)

Basically your swaping live view to photo while going forwards or back / left to right / up and down, unless they have used a crane or drone it should be pretty easy.